# Use variable from another method

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am making a slot machine with JavaScript and have run into an issue when I need to compare variables at the end of a scroll to see if user won or not.

Is it possible to somehow store the variable "randomArrayItem" from the method moveSlots() and use it in the go() method?

I use the moveSlots() method to move each slot separately, but I need to know the randomArrayItem it used to move it so I can compare each slots value to eachother. If they match up, the user is supposed to win.

NOTE THIS WONT RUN BECAUSE I DON"T KNOW HOW TO INSERT MY IMAGES FROM slot1,2,3.  But I posted because I am only asking how to carry the randomArrayItem over to GetLucky(); ? Thanks!

```js
var slot1 = [
'<img class="coffee" src="imgs/temp-coffee-1.jpg" alt="coffee pot icon">',
'<img class="tea" src="imgs/temp-tea-1.jpg" alt="coffee pot icon">',
'<img class="espresso" src="imgs/temp-espresso-1.jpg" alt="coffee pot icon">'
];
var slot2 = [
'<img class="coffee" src="imgs/temp-coffee-1.jpg" alt="coffee pot icon">',
'<img class="tea" src="imgs/temp-tea-1.jpg" alt="coffee pot icon">',
'<img class="espresso" src="imgs/temp-espresso-1.jpg" alt="coffee pot icon">'
];
var slot3 = [
'<img class="coffee" src="imgs/temp-coffee-1.jpg" alt="coffee pot icon">',
'<img class="tea" src="imgs/temp-tea-1.jpg" alt="coffee pot icon">',
'<img class="espresso" src="imgs/temp-espresso-1.jpg" alt="coffee pot icon">'
];

function GetLucky(){

    function getRandomInt(min, max) {
        return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
    }

 
    function go(){
        addSlots();
        moveSlots($('#slot_a'));
        moveSlots($('#slot_b'));
        moveSlots($('#slot_c'));
      
      // NEED TO COMPARE var randomArrayItem from _a, _b, _c to see if they match... ideas???
    }

    function moveSlots(el){
        var time = 500;
        time += Math.round(Math.random()*2000);
        el.stop(true,true);

        var randomArrayItem = getRandomInt(0, 2);

        var marginTop = (-7 * (100)) - (randomArrayItem * 100 ); //change 100 to height placeholder
        
        el.animate(
            {"margin-top":marginTop+"px"},
            {'duration' : time, 'easing' : "easeInOutQuint"}
        );   
    }

    function addSlots(){

        for(i=0; i<20; i++){
            $('#slot_a').append("<div class='content'>" + slot1[getRandomInt(0,2)] + "</div>");
            $('#slot_b').append("<div class='content'>" + slot2[getRandomInt(0,2)] + "</div>");
            $('#slot_c').append("<div class='content'>" + slot3[getRandomInt(0,2)] + "</div>");
        }
    }

}
```

```css
body{
background-color:white;
padding:50px;
margin:50px;
}


.slots {
 font-size:10px;
 font-family:arial,helvetica,sans-serif;
 overflow:hidden;
 width:100px;
 height:100px;
 border:1px solid black;
 float:left;
}

.slots .wrapper{
 width:100px;
}

.slots .slot{
 width:100px;
 height:100px;
 text-align:center;
}
.slot .content {
 width:100px;
 height:100px;
    color:#000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Document</title>
</head>

</html>
<body>
<script src="js/jQuery_v1.12.3.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.easing.1.3.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/scripts.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />


<div style="width:310px">
<div class="slots"  id="slots_a">
 <div class="wrapper" >
  <div id="slot_a" class='slot'><!-- <img src="imgs/temp-tea-1.jpg" alt="coffee pot icon"> --></div>
 </div>
</div>
<div class="slots"  id="slots_b">
 <div class="wrapper" >
  <div id="slot_b" class='slot'><!-- <img src="imgs/temp-coffee-1.jpg" alt="coffee pot icon"> --></div>
 </div>
</div>
<div class="slots"  id="slots_c">
 <div class="wrapper" >
  <div id="slot_c" class='slot'><!-- <img src="imgs/temp-espresso-1.jpg" alt="coffee pot icon"> --></div>
 </div>
</div>
<div style="text-align:center">
<input type="button" value="spin!" onClick="GetLucky();" style="margin-top:4px;">
</div>
</div>

</body>
```

Hard to explain but you will see below.

Comment: No, you cannot access a variable in another method. However, you can move it to the outer scope - for example, create a global array, and put these values there.

Comment: Having </html> after the head is probably not the best start.

Comment: Getting it to run is fairly simple..... change function getlucky() {.... To this var getlucky = {... Then change each internal function to functionname: function() {.... Then change your onClick=... to.. "getlucky.go();"... .So for each internal function you have just add, "this." before it. Example: this.addSlots();

Comment: Apologies... it was a quick copy and paste from a lot of junk i was moving around to test, hence some dumb code like the head tag, etc. Got it answered though. Thanks @SteveKline! I am trying to do that now... That seems way cleaner!

Comment: I supposed I should point out one more semi-important flaw. Each time it executes, it adds 20+ child objects with AddSlots. Easy fix with a top level var addedslots = false; and add if (addedslots != true) { before the for statement. Then after the for closing bracket, put addedslots = true;. This could get aggressively large over a series of 5-10 minutes of random play if it gets becomes a larger project. 60 Images on the first run... by 5 runs, you've loaded the images 6 times. Not sure if it keeps memory low for each instance but it does clutter up a bit.

Comment: yeah, I know... the way it's set up though is by just decreasing margin-top... So the more they press it, the more divs they need.  I am working on having a modal pop up after each play, it will have a win or lose illustration. after user closes that it will reset maybe? ideas?  I am having trouble with the modal though too, I can't seem to call the method i need... i have it posted too, ive tried everything I feel like [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37743468/calling-method-is-coming-back-undefined)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to return the randomArrayItem from move slots and trigger the execution of go by calling it `go();`

```
function GetLucky(){

    function getRandomInt(min, max) {
        return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
    }


    function go(){
        addSlots();

       randomArrayItem1 = moveSlots($('#slot_a'));
       randomArrayItem2 = moveSlots($('#slot_b'));
       randomArrayItem3 = moveSlots($('#slot_c'));
       if (randomArrayItem1 ==  randomArrayItem2 &&  randomArrayItem2 == randomArrayItem3) console.log('win');

    }

    function moveSlots(el){
        var time = 500;
        time += Math.round(Math.random()*2000);
        el.stop(true,true);

        var randomArrayItem = getRandomInt(0, 2);

        var marginTop = (-7 * (100)) - (randomArrayItem * 100 ); //change 100 to height placeholder

        el.animate(
            {"margin-top":marginTop+"px"},
            {'duration' : time, 'easing' : "easeInOutQuint"}
        );  
        return randomArrayItem;
    }

   function addSlots(){

    for(i=0; i<20; i++){
        $('#slot_a').append("<div class='content'>" + slot1[getRandomInt(0,2)] + "</div>");
        $('#slot_b').append("<div class='content'>" + slot2[getRandomInt(0,2)] + "</div>");
        $('#slot_c').append("<div class='content'>" + slot3[getRandomInt(0,2)] + "</div>");
    }
}
go();
}
```

Comment: you realize this doesn't ever actually call any functions or expose/return any functions to be called, and therefore does exactly nothing as is..

Comment: oh, you mean the one you literally just now added.. congratulations it works now

Comment: dang Pootie, aint he all about the love in "real life"?? lol Thanks @madalin ivascu!! that works

Answer (score 2):

You can store variables by having a function return a value and have that function on the right hand of an assignment operation.

For instance:

```
var randomInt = getRandomInt();
```

EDIT: That said, if randomInt is inside a function, another function will not be able to access it. Example:

```
function i() { var x = 7; }
var a = x+x;
```

Var a in the above code will be undefined since the variable is not defined globally (only within its function)

Just a general note too...your code never seems to actually executes go(). It only defines it via function go() etc.

Comment: Sorry to the editor, I made an edit when you edited and it rejected your edits. Give it another try if this still needs it :)